# Parse non array JSON with php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am developing a backend in php+codeigniter which connects to a data providing service that returns a JSON such as the following:

```
{
"code": "36397_26320",
"type": "TEAMS",
"4522": {
    "id": "4522",
    "code": "324",
    "name": "IT24354"
},
"4524": {
    "id": "4524",
    "code": "1234",
    "name": "IT24234"
},
"4527": {
    "id": "4527",
    "code": "2134",
    "name": "IT2678"
},
"4529": {
    "id": "4529",
    "code": "653",
    "name": "IT3546",
    "info":{
         "type1":
         {
            "type":"1",
            "url":"www.someurl.com",
            "date":"some date"
         },
         "type2":
         {
            "type":"2",
            "url":"www.someurl.com",
            "date":"some date"
         }

      }
},
"4530": {
    "id": "4530",
    "code": "3456",
    "name": "IT8769"
},
"4534": {
    "id": "4534",
    "code": "6453",
    "name": "IT3456"
},
"4537": {
    "id": "4537",
    "code": "76856",
    "name": "IT2676"
},
"4540": {
    "id": "4540",
    "code": "5768",
    "name": "IT23454"
},
"16225": {
    "id": "16225",
    "code": "4675",
    "name": "IT90687"
}
}
```

And I want to get the info inside those number identifiers such that the output JSON encoded would look the following way:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "4522",
        "code": "324",
        "name": "IT24354"
    },
    {
        "id": "4524",
        "code": "1234",
        "name": "IT24234"
    },
    {
        "id": "4527",
        "code": "2134",
        "name": "IT2678"
    },
    {
        "id": "4529",
        "code": "653",
        "name": "IT3546",
        "info":[
         {
            "type":"1",
            "url":"www.someurl.com",
            "date":"some date"
         },
         {
            "type":"2",
            "url":"www.someurl.com",
            "date":"some date"
         }

         ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4530",
        "code": "3456",
        "name": "IT8769"
    },
    {
        "id": "4534",
        "code": "6453",
        "name": "IT3456"
    },
    {
        "id": "4537",
        "code": "76856",
        "name": "IT2676"
    },
    {
        "id": "4540",
        "code": "5768",
        "name": "IT23454"
    },
    {
        "id": "16225",
        "code": "4675",
        "name": "IT90687"
    }
]
}
```

My issue is that for example, I do not know if the item has the field "info" such as in item 4529, or also at the item identifier level, there are two fields called code and type that have no further information.

Is there any easy way to do such operation? or is performing a foreach for as many levels as I want to obtain the only way to do it? how do I identify if the key in the json contains more key value pairs?

Thank you all!

Comment: Create a function to walk the array. use `gettype($var)` to test for `object/array`, and if it's an object/array, call the function again. Only need a few lines for this.

Comment: You can use `json_decode` with the extra argument set to `true` to turn your JSON into a PHP array and use `foreach` to interact thru it. See the PHP manual on how to use `json_decode`. From there you could easily use for instance `isset` to know weather or not `info` is present within that item, `if (isset($item['info'])) { //bla bla }` or `is_array` to know if an item is an array.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy As you can notice, there is no object array in that json. Is there any function to determine if it has more than one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all very much, It is a bit tricky but I ended up doing the following, since it allows me to explore the complete json without knowing if key value is another JSON. Right now it returns the same input json, but to change output to array just add brackets to the return value when recursing

```
$response[$key][] = $this->read_non_array_json(json_encode($value));
```

Improvements highly welcomed:

```
private function read_non_array_json($data)
{

    $json = json_decode($data);

    if(is_object($json))
    {
        if(isset($json->id))
        {
            //obtain values, use a global array maybe to save info or something...
                        $id = $json->id;
                        $code = $json->code;
                        $name = $json->name;
        }
        if(isset($json->info)
        {
              //more code...
        }

        foreach($json as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_object($value))
            {
                $response[$key]= $this->read_non_array_json(json_encode($value));
            }
            else
            {
                $response[$key] = $value;
            }

        }

        return $response;

    }
    else
    {

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the first json object you supplied and putting it in the `$json` variable for this example:

```
<?php 

$json = '{
"code": "36397_26320",
"type": "TEAMS",
"4522": {
    "id": "4522",
    "code": "324",
    "name": "IT24354"
},
"4524": {
    "id": "4524",
    "code": "1234",
    "name": "IT24234"
},
"4527": {
    "id": "4527",
    "code": "2134",
    "name": "IT2678"
},
"4529": {
    "id": "4529",
    "code": "653",
    "name": "IT3546",
    "info":{
         "type1":
         {
            "type":"1",
            "url":"www.someurl.com",
            "date":"some date"
         },
         "type2":
         {
            "type":"2",
            "url":"www.someurl.com",
            "date":"some date"
         }

      }
},
"4530": {
    "id": "4530",
    "code": "3456",
    "name": "IT8769"
},
"4534": {
    "id": "4534",
    "code": "6453",
    "name": "IT3456"
},
"4537": {
    "id": "4537",
    "code": "76856",
    "name": "IT2676"
},
"4540": {
    "id": "4540",
    "code": "5768",
    "name": "IT23454"
},
"16225": {
    "id": "16225",
    "code": "4675",
    "name": "IT90687"
}
}';
?>
```

Now we can create a json object to access the data:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Allowing us to itterate through that data object and see if `info` is set:

```
foreach($data as $item){
    if(isset($item->info)){
        // info found...do what you need to...
        print $item->id . " <br />";print_r($item->info);
    }
}
```

Warranting a return of this:

```
4529 
stdClass Object
(
    [type1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => 1
            [url] => www.someurl.com
            [date] => some date
        )

    [type2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => 2
            [url] => www.someurl.com
            [date] => some date
        )

)
```

#### Example

Comment: Thank you @Darren I actually ended up using the isset function to analyze values in the json.

Comment: @RobertoNovelo it's a pleasure :)